# knexjs deleting rows from parent/child tables using transactions

Tags: node.js, transactions, relational-database, knex.js

I am using knexjs to delete a row from a table.  This table has referenced rows in another table, so I need to delete those child rows first in order to delete the parent row.  I want to use a transaction so that I can rollback child deletions if the parent deletion fails.

This is my code, but it seems to hang on the second query:

```
return Bookshelf.knex.transaction((t : any) => {
        return Bookshelf.knex('user_patient_groups')
            .transacting(t)
            .del()
            .where('patient_group_id', groupID)
            .then(() => {
                return Bookshelf.knex('patient_groups')
                    .del()
                    .where('patient_group_id', groupID)
                    .then(t.commit)
                    .catch(t.rollback);
            });
    });
```

can anybody see if i'm doing something wrong here?  The knexjs documentation is not very extensive.

Answer (score 0):

You should omit calling

```
.then(t.commit)
.catch(t.rollback)
```

`knex` will manage your transaction for you if **promise is returned in transaction callback**. So with your `.catch` you suppress error passing through promise chain and transaction sees fulfilled promise.

Otherwise, do not return promise from your transaction (remove `return`s) and leave `commit` and `rollback`.